# What is the use of asBitmap() in Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

Can anyone please explain to me when, where and why the `asBitmap()` function is called in Glide?

I am currently using Glide 3.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

asBitmap() is used when you want to edit, transform, or decorate bitmap before displaying it in ImageView or another view (as you cannot use glide with another view except ImageView)

like fetch image as bitmap before setBackgroundDrawable (which created from bitmap) to be a background of LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Use `asBitmap()` function when you need to load bitmap without attaching it to `ImageView`.

For example:

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(image)
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                }
            });
```